# Consider $f_n, f \in L^2(d\mu)$, $f_n(x) \to f(x)$ a.e. and $\|f_n\|_2 \to \|f\|_2$. Use Egorov's theorem to show that $f_n \to f$ in $L^2(d\mu)$.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

> Q: Consider $f \in L^2(d\mu)$, $\{ f_n \} \in L^2(d\mu)$, $f_n(x) \to f(x)$ a.e. and $\int |f_n|^2 \, d\mu \mathop{\longrightarrow}\limits_{n \to \infty} \int |f|^2 \, d\mu$. Use Egorov's theorem to show that $f_n \to f$ in $L^2(d\mu)$.

For any $\epsilon$, by Egorov's Theorem, there exists a $A_\epsilon$ such that $f_n$ converges uniformly to $f$ in $A_\epsilon$ and that the measure of the complement $m(A_\epsilon^c) < \epsilon$. Then for large enough $n$, $|f_n - f| < \epsilon$ for all $x \in A_\epsilon$.

If $f_n$ and $f$ are supported on a set of finite measure, which is not given, then it would be simple to show that $\int_{A_\epsilon} (f - f_n)^2 \, d\mu$ is arbitrarily small.

If $f_n$ and $f$ are bounded, which is not given, then it would be simple to show that $\int_{A_\epsilon^c} (f - f_n)^2 \, d\mu$ is arbitrarily small.

However, we are not given that $f_n$ and $f$ are bounded or supported on a set of finite measure. So, I'm not sure how to approach this problem.

I'm not using the given that:

\begin{align*}
  \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \int |f_n|^2 \, d\mu &= \int |f|^2 \, d\mu \\
\end{align*}

Which means that the $L^2$ norm of $f_n$ approaches that of $f$. I presume that I'm supposed to use that but I don't see how.

Comment: The title does not match the question.

Comment: so sorry, fixed the title.

Comment: Egorov is for finite measure spaces. So, the finiteness of $\mu$ is implicit in the question, I think.

Comment: as I wrote in the OP, with a set of finite measure, you can show that $\int_{A_\epsilon} (f - f_n)^2$ is arbitrarily small, but how can you show that for $\int_{E - A_\epsilon} (f - f_n)^2$. $m(E - A_\epsilon) < \epsilon$ but if $f$ isn't bounded, that integral isn't necessarily finite.

Comment: Duplicate of [$f_n(x) \to f(x)$ and $\int |f_n|^2 \, d\mu \to \int |f|^2 \, d\mu$. Use Egorov's theorem to show $f_n \to f$ in $L^2(d\mu)$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3172054/f-nx-to-fx-and-int-f-n2-d-mu-to-int-f2-d-mu-use-egorov)